# validatorMessage override other message

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

My email input field has two validator, the first one uses f:validateRegex, the second one use f:validator. Default message displayed when validateRegex was fail ('value is invalid'),
validator message displayed when validator was fail ('email is already in use').
It is fine until I customize f:validateRegex message with validatorMessage.
Input field now display the new message ('email is invalid') for both which is unexpected.

So How can I keep f:validator message?

HTML:

```
<p:inputText id="phoneNo" value="#{bean.phoneNo}" 
validatorMessage="#{msg['errors.phone.invalid']}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="#{msg['pattern.regex.phone']}" />
    <f:validator binding="#{phoneNoValidator}" />
</p:inputText> 
<p:message for="phoneNo" showDetail="true" />
```

Validator class:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
    Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    fc = context;
    String phoneNo = String.valueOf(value);
    if (driverBO.isExistMobileNo(phoneNo )) {
        FacesMessage message = getErrorMessage(Errors.PHONE_DUPLICATED);
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you already noticed "validatorMessage override other message".

f:validateRegex is also not very convenient for message customization.

1. remove attribute: validatorMessage
2. remove tag: f:validateRegex
3. Move to Bean Validation which is easy to customize and for i18n by adding the followin annotation in the bean:

The example code:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z\\. ]+", message = "{pattern.regex.phoneMessage}")
private String phoneNo;
```

The message need to be defined in : ValidationMessages.properties for default locale and in ValidationMessages_xx.properties for 'xx' locale.

See a great [article](http://www.codebulb.ch/2015/05/jsf-validation-localization-i18n-by-example-part-2.html) about.